# React Native WebView video dont allow fullscreen with other contents

Tags: react-native

I have a webview with a video, below the webview I have other content,
the problem is when i click the fullscreen bottom dont work the fullscreen.

the video stay inside the View.

below everything I have Tab navigation, I need to hide that too

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, component } from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Image} from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import moment from 'moment';



    function Home(props){
        const  {navigation} = props;

    return (
             <View style={{flex:1}}>
                      <View style={{flex:1,padding:0,margin:0}}>
                        <WebView style={styles.webViewContent}
                        source={{ uri: 'https://urlvideo' }}
                        originWhitelist={['https://*']}
                        allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
                        allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
                        javaScriptEnabled={true}
                        scalesPageToFit={true}
                        domStorageEnabled={true}
                       
                        />
                      </View>
                      <View style={{flex:2}}>
                        <Text>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc arcu mi, posuere a euismod a, 
                        blandit ut ex. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque a libero laoreet, vestibulum diam gravida, 
                        vehicula velit. 
                        Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, 
                        per inceptos himenaeos. 
                        Morbi eleifend ornare massa in iaculis. 
                        Nam consectetur nunc in gravida laoreet. 
                        Aliquam vitae lacus ac magna varius convallis. 
                        Aenean venenatis sapien ut turpis posuere eleifend. 
                        Praesent a malesuada arcu. Curabitur et nunc massa. 
                        Proin sed dolor ac orci sodales accumsan. 
                        Morbi hendrerit nisl nunc, ac aliquet massa tincidunt a.
                        </Text>
                      </View>
            </View>
    );
    }
        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        webViewContent: {
              flex:1,
              top:0,
              marginBottom:0,
              padding:0,margin:0,
           
            },
        });
export default Home;
```

I have this screen:

[image]

what I need is when I click on fullscreen the video takes the whole screen and hide the other content and the navigation tab

Answer (score 0):

if you want the video to take the whole screen and overlap the content,
you have to place:

**scrollEnabled={false}**

```
<WebView style={styles.webViewContent}
     source={{ uri: 'https://www.urlvideo.com/' }}
     originWhitelist={['https://*']}
     allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
     allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
     javaScriptEnabled={true}
     scalesPageToFit={true}
     domStorageEnabled={true}
     scrollEnabled={false}
/>
```